# Should I use a 1H or a 2H as a battle mage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I really love the idea of a warrior charging into battle with the powers of destructive magic as his ally.  Being brand new to Skyrim, I did some reading on the topic but haven't been able to find the answer to my question: Should I go 1H with a spell at the ready, or 2H and switch to dual-handed magical destruction as needed?

Comment: Mostly a matter of preference as both could work. Whichever you choose, the favorites bar will be your friend to quickly switch between whatever spells/weapons you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

It makes more sense for a battle mage to be one handed.  That way you aren't forced to make the decision to give up one of your preferred source of damage in order to use the other.  Other than the master level spells, you can cast everything else with 1 hand while swinging a weapon in the other, this makes for great versatility.

Also, you can be more defensive if you choose by equipping a ward spell in one hand while swinging a sword in the other.  A good ward spell can stop most things including pesky dragon breaths.

Comment: That was the original image I had in my head as well.  But then I read a very convincing argument (links to allocated points and all) that had me second-guessing myself.  Thinking that I could dual-cast until they close in then pwn them with a 2h.

Comment: @Indelaceo the problem with 2 handers is their super slow swing time.  Even though they look cool you will never beat the DPS output of a 1 hander once you factor in enchantments and smithing.  The only real reason to use one is for some of the unique 2 handers sch as the [Bloodskaal blade](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bloodskal_Blade) from dragonborn